# I'm trying to make a responsive portfolio site

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, github

I'm trying to create my portfolio, and I don't know how to solve this bug.

Whenever I open the webpage I hosted on GitHub [https://supercaaio.github.io/MeuSite/] via Firefox, I get this

[image: The navbar working properly and beautifully]:

Whenever I open it on google chrome I get this:

[image: The navbar stacking all things together]

HTML

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scroll-up-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#">
                <img src="images/meuperfil.png" alt="Caio Santos" width="55px">
                <span></span></a></div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#home" class="menu-btn">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">Sobre mim</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="menu-btn">Meus Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills" class="menu-btn">Minhas Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teams" class="menu-btn">Meus Projetos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contate-me</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.logo img {
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar.sticky{
    padding: 25px 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar .max-width{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .logo a span{
    color: rgb(20, 238, 238);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span{
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar.sticky .logo a span::after {
    color: #00FFFF;
    content: " Caio Santos";
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.navbar .menu li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a{
    display: block;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 25px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover{
    color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome version Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) and its working properly here: https://prnt.sc/tKNO2aLNwrYc . Have you tried clearing your cache and refresh the page?

Comment: I did try to CTRL+F5 and it is the same! Could it be related to my screen resolution? Any idea on what could it be ?

Comment: Have you checked the website in incognito mode? I have no idea of the cause, but from my experiences, it may be caused by faulty CSS and usually clearing the cache (ctrl shift R, ctrl F5, depends on your browser) will fix it. I have tried zooming out your website as well, and it works fine here.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are a genius of some kind hahaha I did try to enter as incognito and it works perfectly. I'm just scared that some other person might have the same error as I had and may think that it's 'cause of my bad CSS skills (They won't be entirely wrong lol)

Comment: I don't think that's the cause XD Anyway, I'm glad that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just click CTRL+F5, and that will fix bcz it works for me in chrome, so just clear cache refresh page and thats it.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work at least on my PC. Someone up there told me to try incognito mode and it somehow worked. Do you have any other idea on why it could be happening ?